# Holding a reference to C++ object with JNI (and USB programming)

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, usb

I've got a USB recording device, with an API written in C++. I would like to interface it with an existing Java application, where upon initialisation of the application it connects to the device, then can subsequently start and stop recording, rather than having to reconnect for each recording. This would require a reference to the connection at the Java end. Would it be possible to wrap the C++ code in a class and keep a reference to an object of it at the Java end to call a start/stop recording method when required?

Otherwise the API does not add that much additional functionality, as the byte commands to send to the device to start and stop recording are fairly simple. Would it be simpler to interface directly with the USB? I've little experience with JNI and no experience with USB programming.

Unfortunately I cannot share any sample code from this project.

Comment: Create a `unique_ptr` of the C++ object on the heap. Have a JNI C++ function that returns a `jlong` and return in the body: `unique_ptr.get()`. Have the corresponding Java JNI function return a `long`. Without `unique_ptr` and `one static object`, you could allocate on the heap using `new` and then destruct using `delete` from a java shutdown thread. OR a `vector` of `unique_ptr` for each instance of the object.

Comment: What you want need is the probably the Peer Object pattern.  Much safer (and more portable) than casting pointers into `jlong`s is to pass a handle to Java-land and maintain std::map<handle, std::unique_ptr<T>> on the C++ side. This gives you the opportunity to validate the object actually exists on calls.  After all, you need something to *own* the `std::unique_ptr` - as you won't get any of the cleverness of c++11's smart pointers when you `reinterpret_cast` them to integral types.